# Program doesnt show most frequent number

Tags: c

Problem: I am trying to find most frequent six numbers in an array of random integers but I am only finding my loop count.

```
#include   <stdio.h>
#include   <stdlib.h>
#include   <time.h>

//Salih Atacan Karagöz 210201055
int main()
{
    long x=210201055; //password
    long y=0;
    printf("Enter password:");
    scanf("%d",&y);



    if(x==y)       //password check if statement is true progrom continues
    {
        int tekrar[49]= {0};    //array for counting repeating numbers
        int numbers[49]= {0};   //array for creating random numbers
        int z;                     //integer for loop counter
        int counter=0;          //counter for loop
        int i;
        int j=0;
        int high=0;
        printf("Enter loop count:");
        scanf("%d",&z);
        srand(time(NULL));
        for(counter=1; counter<=z; counter++)   //loop will do under these lines z times
        {
            i=0;
            while(i<6)                  //every time we need 6 random numbers so loop need to create max 6 numbers (0,1,2,3,4,5,)
            {
                i++;
                numbers[i]=rand()%50+1;     //+1 for prevent creating zeros mod 49 for creating numbers below 49
                tekrar[numbers[i]]++;       //array +1 t its value every time same number comes
            }
        }
        for(i=1; i<=49; i++)
        {
            printf("%d->%d\t",i,tekrar[i]);     //for printing created numbers
        }

        printf("\n -----------\tMost Frequent Six Numbers\t-------------\n");
        printf(":(");

        int count;
        int maxCount = 0;
        int maxValue = 0;

        for(j=0;j<9;j++){
            count=0;
            for(i=0; i<49; i++){
                if (numbers[i]==numbers[i+1]){
                    count++;
                }
                if(count>maxCount){
                    maxCount==count;
                }
            }
            maxValue=numbers[i];
        }
        printf("Number: %d", maxValue);
        printf("\n-----------GUESS-----------\n");          //we will use bouble sort here
        printf(":(");

    }
    else   //if password is wrong program continues from here
    {
        printf("Wrong Password");
    }
}
```

Comment: Before you can find the 6 most frequent numbers, you need to be able to run your code without run-time errors.  `int tekrar[49] = {0};` is one element too small for the block:  `for(i=1; i<=49; i++){printf("%d->%d\t",i,tekrar[i]);}`  Index `i` will go to 49 in your loop, but the biggest index value for `tekrar` should be limited to 48.  Also, I assume by _bouble sort_, you intend _bubble sort_?  Look up ***[qsort(...)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm)***

Comment: @CiocomoTrombetta Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yeah i missed that one. One of the small problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 50

int main() {

    //Access
    int numbers[SIZE+1], randomNumbers, count, innerCount;
    int pcPassword = 2, userPassword = 0, frequentNumber[6], frequentNumberCount[6];
    printf("Enter password:");
    scanf("%d", &userPassword);

    if(pcPassword != userPassword) {
        printf("Wrong Password");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("How many random Numbers do you want:\n>");
    scanf(" %d", &randomNumbers);

    //initlaized
    for(count = 0; count <= SIZE; count++)
        numbers[count] = 0;

    //Random Numbers
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(count = 0; count < randomNumbers; count++)
        numbers[rand() % 50 + 1]++;

    //Print
    for(count = 1; count <= SIZE; count++) {
        if((count-1) % 6 == 0)
            printf("\n");
        printf("%4d -> %3d", count, numbers[count]);
    }


    //initlaized
    for(count = 0; count < 6; count++) {
        frequentNumber[count] = 0;
        frequentNumberCount[count] = 0;
    }


    //Get frequent numbers
    for(count = 1; count <= SIZE; count++) {
        for(innerCount = 0; innerCount < 6; innerCount++) {

            if(numbers[count] > frequentNumberCount[innerCount]) {
                if(innerCount+1 <= 5)
                    frequentNumber[innerCount+1] = frequentNumber[innerCount];

                frequentNumber[innerCount] = count;
                frequentNumberCount[innerCount] = numbers[count];
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    //Print
    printf("\n\nThe 6 most frequent numbers are:\n");
    for(count = 0; count < 6; count++)
        printf("%d. -> Number: %3d Count: %3d\n", count+1, frequentNumber[count], frequentNumberCount[count]);

    return 0;

}
```

Input:

```
2     //Password
1200  //Random Numbers
```

Output:

```
Enter password:2
How many random Numbers do you want:
>1200

   1 ->  23   2 ->  21   3 ->  24   4 ->  24   5 ->  25   6 ->  28
   7 ->  22   8 ->  22   9 ->  25  10 ->  27  11 ->  27  12 ->  20
  13 ->  14  14 ->  29  15 ->  28  16 ->  20  17 ->  22  18 ->  20
  19 ->  29  20 ->  25  21 ->  35  22 ->  21  23 ->  24  24 ->  23
  25 ->  21  26 ->  24  27 ->  12  28 ->  33  29 ->  23  30 ->  17
  31 ->  33  32 ->  21  33 ->  24  34 ->  23  35 ->  33  36 ->  21
  37 ->  22  38 ->  28  39 ->  30  40 ->  18  41 ->  16  42 ->  29
  43 ->  24  44 ->  29  45 ->  30  46 ->  20  47 ->  19  48 ->  26
  49 ->  18  50 ->  28

The 6 most frequent numbers are:
1. -> Number:  21 Count:  35
2. -> Number:  28 Count:  33
3. -> Number:  31 Count:  33
4. -> Number:  35 Count:  33
5. -> Number:  39 Count:  30
6. -> Number:  45 Count:  30
```